# Capture Output is empty for SSH Actions

Tags: cloudera, oozie

I'm running a simple Workflow with Oozie 4.0.0. I need to run bash scripts through SSH actions and then capture the stdout.

This is the xml:

```
<workflow-app name="Test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="LS"/>
    <action name="LS">
        <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
            <host>user@host</host>
            <command>ls</command>
              <capture-output/>
        </ssh>
        <ok to="Mail"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="Mail">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
            <to>myaddress@mail.com</to>
            <subject>Test mail</subject>
            <body>${wf:actionData('LS')}</body>
        </email>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

The body of the mail contains only this:

```
{}
```

The same script with shell action works without problems, but I need the SSH action.
I'm going crazy, anybody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. 
Seeing the logs I've noticed that the SShActionExecutor look at the wrong stdout file. This is the the command that I found in the log

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 workflow@redhat5 cat oozie-oozi/0000008-140708170302737-oozie-oozi-W/fileProcessing--ssh/22350.0000008-140708170302737-oozie-oozi-W@fileProcessing@1.stdout
```

But the generated stdout file is `/home/instadoc/oozie-oozi/0000008-140708170302737-oozie-oozi-W/fileProcessing--ssh/22350.0000008-140708170302737-oozie-oozi-W@fileProcessing@0.stdout`

If you relaunch the action the ID that prepend the .stdout extension could vary (ie: @9.stdout, @4.stdout) but the SShActionExecutor looks always at @0.stdout.